# Struggling to correctly utilize the str.find() function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm trying to use the `str.find()` and it keeps raising an error, what am I doing wrong?

I have a matrix where the 1st column is numbers and the 2nd is an abbreviation assigned to those letters. the abbrevations are either ED, LI or NA, I'm trying to find the positions that correspond to those letters so that I can plot a scatter graph that is colour coded to match those 3 groups.

```
mat=sio.loadmat('PBMC_extract.mat') #loading the data file into python
data=mat['spectra']
data_name=mat['name'] #calling in varibale
data_name = pd.DataFrame(data_name) #converting intoa readable matrix

pca=PCA(n_components=20)  # preforms pca on data with 20 components
pca.fit(data) #fits to data set
datatrans=pca.transform(data)  #transforms data using PCA

# plotting the graph that accounts for majority of data and noise
plt.plot(np.cumsum(pca.explained_variance_ratio_))
plt.xlabel('Number of components')
plt.ylabel('Cumulative explained variance')


fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = Axes3D(fig)

#str.find to find individual positions of anticoagulants
str.find(data_name,'ED')

#renaming data for easiness
x_data=datatrans[0:35,0]
y_data=datatrans[0:35,1]
z_data=datatrans[0:35,2]

x2_data=datatrans[36:82,0]
y2_data=datatrans[36:82,1]
z2_data=datatrans[36:82,2]

x3_data=datatrans[83:97,0]
y3_data=datatrans[83:97,1]
z3_data=datatrans[83:97,2]

# scatter plot of score of PC1,2,3
ax1.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data,c='b', marker="^")
ax1.scatter(x2_data, y2_data, z2_data,c='r', marker="o")
ax1.scatter(x3_data, y3_data, z3_data,c='g', marker="s")

ax1.set_xlabel('PC 1')
ax1.set_ylabel('PC 2')
ax1.set_zlabel('PC 3')


plt.show()
```

the error that keeps showing up is the following;

```
  File "/Users/emma/Desktop/Final year project /working example of colouring data", line 49, in <module>
    str.find(data_name,'ED')

TypeError: descriptor 'find' requires a 'str' object but received a 'DataFrame'
```

Comment: I believe the following line is causing your issue: `data_name = pd.DataFrame(data_name)`

Could it be a mistake? It looks like it should rather be  `data = pd.DataFrame(data)`

Answer (score 2):

The error is because the `find` method expects a `str` object instead of a `DataFrame` object. As PiRK mentioned the problem is you're replacing the `data_name` variable here:

```
data_name = pd.DataFrame(data_name)
```

I believe it should be:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data_name)
```

Also, although `str.find(data_name,'ED')` works, the suggested way to is to pass only the search term like this:

```
data_name.find('ED')
```

Comment: when I use data_name.find('ED') I get the following error message 
    File "/Users/emma/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4376, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: Hi Emma, this is happening because you are replacing the `data_name` variable. You must fix first what I said above and only then change the `find` call

Answer (score 0):

the proper syntax would be

```
data_name.find('ED')
```

look at the examples here

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/find

EDIT 1
though I just noticed data_name is a pandas DataFrame, so that won't work?  What exactly are you trying to do?

your broken function call isn't even returning into a variable?  So it's hard to answer your question?

Comment: I'm trying to call the all the ED variables out of the matrix and assign a colour, I then want to call of the LI variable out of the matrix and assign a different colour and the same for NA. 

I had to use the following line of 
data_name = pd.DataFrame(data_name)
so that I could view the data contained in the matrix, before I did this I could access it, I kept getting the message that the array wasn't supported. adding the extra line allowed me to view the matrix